# Don't see “Bluetooth Radios” and bluetooth not working on Bootcamp Windows 7

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, bluetooth

I attempted to ask this question at superuser.com but so far I have not received any help. 
So for the past couple of days I've been trying to get my Logitech Dinovo Bluetooth Keyboard working on my Windows 7 partition. Unfortunately it is not finding any bluetooth devices. I have no issues whatsoever on the OSX partition so I know it's not a hardware issue. Additionally, it seems that I can find Bluetooth settings when I right-click on "Apple Internal Keyboard and Trackpad" but when I try to "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer" I receive this error. I also don't see the Bluetooth icon in the system tray.

This issue has been really frustrating so any help would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there has gone something wrong with installing the Windows supporting Software. You can try re-installing this by using your installation discs, or you can download it [on the software page on the Apple website](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#bootcamp%20windows%20drivers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already re-installed the Bootcamp 4.0 drivers and still doesn't see Bluetooth. This is extremely frustrating because I can't figure this out. Seems like there should be a simple explanation.